# Is there a way to return the name of a Navigation Path in SwiftUI 4?

Tags: swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm trying to implement Pop to Root functionality in an app with a Tab View.

Here's my class where I define my Navigation Paths. Each path is assigned to a Tab. Tabs share child views that have a button that calls the reset() function. Right now "featuredPath" is hard coded in the function. What I'd like would be for the function to `switch` on the Path name and reset the correct one.

In order for me to do that, I would need the child view to return the active Path name when the button is tapped.

Is this possible?

```
class Router: ObservableObject {
    @Published var featuredPath = NavigationPath()
    @Published var favoritePath = NavigationPath()
    @Published var searchPath = NavigationPath()
    func reset() {
        featuredPath = NavigationPath()
    }
}
```

```
struct MainViewScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: Router

    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
            NavigationStack(path: $router.featuredPath) {
                FeaturedContainer()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Featured", systemImage: "star.circle")
            }
            NavigationStack(path: $router.favoritePath) {
                FavoritesContainer()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Favorites", systemImage: "heart.circle")
            }
            NavigationStack(path: $router.searchPath) {
                SearchContainer()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Search", systemImage: "magnifyingglass.circle")
            }
        }
    }
}
```